# What is concept of Kotlin intent?

Tags: kotlin

I want to understand the concept behind this Kotlin intent.  What does `Activity::class.java`
 mean in Kotlin ?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass

Comment: @EvanWieland I'd say zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin is designed to be interoperable with Java. Pretty much all Java code can be called from Kotlin and vice versa without any issues.

What does `Activity::class.java` ?

Consider this expression `val c = MyClass::class`, In it the reference is a value of type [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html).

To obtain a Java class reference, we need to use the [.java](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) property on a KClass instance.

If you execute below code

```
var ktString = String::class
println(ktString)

var javaString = String::class.java
println(javaString)
```

Output will be

```
class kotlin.String
class java.lang.String
```

`.java` helps to get mapped type between Java and Kotlin at runtime. Please refer [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) for list of mapped types.